# Find a String for an Intent in another Activity in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, string, android-intent

a have this brief problem:

[The definition of the String is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZMm2.png)

[Here, the String isn't reconized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R15pb.png)

Why isn't it reconized? it says "Can't resolve symbol "EXTRA_MESSAGE" "
Thanks you if you help me, and please excuse my bad english, i'm actually french

Answer (score 0):

problem resolved : i needed to add this line:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw0nW.png)